# Matching a Route Based on the Host disconnect me only on the current page

Tags: php, symfony

I've got a route based on a host with a placeholder :

```php
#[Route(
        '/',
        name: 'action',
        host: '{actionCode}.%router.request_context.host%',
    )]
    public function action(
        string $actionCode)
```

I'm logged but if I access the route above, it disconnected me but only on this page and if I click on login button, I'm redirect because I'm already logged.
Now if I delete the placeholder {actionCode}, everything works (I'm logged). I don't know why the placeholder disconnect me only on this page.

Any idea ?

Comment: What's your `session` configuration? Specifically the [`cookie_domain`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#cookie-domain) parameter? You need a leading dot to allow all subdomains.

Comment: I haven't the cookie_domain, only cookie_samesite

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved, I added in my config.yaml :

```php
cookie_domain: '.myUrl'
        cookie_lifetime: 0
        save_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/sessions'
        name: SFSESSID
```

thanks @msg for the clue